# -XX:-PrintCompilation logging method

Tags: java, jvm

When the JVM logs the compilation/decompilation of the class of my program, does it log just before starting the compilation/decompilation or just after it has finished to compile/decompile?

I use `-XX:+PrintCompilation` for asking JVM to log.

Thanks,

Romain

Comment: I tried to find this in the code (see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/services) but couldn't. My guess is that it prints the information at various places during the compilation (i.e. several times at different places).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this study](https://gist.github.com/rednaxelafx/1165804#file_notes.md), which is one of the few reference on the subject:

> Size
>
> This is the size of the original bytecodes of the method. It's NOT the
>   size of the generated native code. The CompileTask isn't even executed
>   yet when PrintCompilation prints out the log; it couldn't have known
>   the size of the generated code in advance.

It is printed before the compilation. That is why the size is the original one, not the optimized one.

Answer (score 5):

According to HotSpot sources `PrintCompilation` prints a line just before starting the compilation of a method (see [CompileBroker::invoke_compiler_on_method](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u60/hotspot/file/ba66650acf63/src/share/vm/compiler/compileBroker.cpp#l1703)).

To issue additional compiler info after the compilation is finished, use

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompilation2
```

and/or

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+TraceNMethodInstalls
```

Comment: perfect answer, I wish I could +200 or something

Answer (score 1):

> does it log just before starting the compilation/decompilation or just after it has finished to compile/decompile?

The compilation of these methods is in the background and the logging of these messages is asynchronous. i.e. it can be significantly delayed.  So when you see the logging is no indication of when you wrote it.

The generated code is always much larger than the byte code.  The JVM "knows" the original size of the byte code which it uses for a number of metrics, even after it has compiled the code and has to re-compile it.  The fact it prints the original size, is no indication of when the message is triggered.

---

The option `-XX:-PrintCompilation` turns it off when it is already off by default.  The HotSpot documentation is slightly confusing in that it shows you the option which is the default.  This means you actually want `-XX:+PrintCompilation`

BTW It also means that a lot of options I see used were always the default as documented, i.e. people set them not realising they haven't changed anything.

Comment: Hi,My question contains an error. I meant "I use -XX:+PrintCompilation" instead of "I use -XX:-PrintCompilation"